# Is a bijective smooth map of the closed disk with invertible differential a diffeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, inverse-function-theorem

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the **closed** unit disk. Let $f:D \to D$ be a smooth **bijective** map with everywhere invertible differential.

> Is $f$ a diffeomorphism of the closed disk?

Here is what I know: The assumptions imply* that $f(D^o) \subseteq D^o$. Since $f$ is surjective, we also have $f(\partial D) \supseteq \partial D$.

The problem is that I am not sure that $f(\partial D) \subseteq \partial D$. If this was the case, then $f$ [would be a diffeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984346/is-a-map-with-invertible-differential-that-maps-boundary-to-boundary-a-local-dif).

Note that I assume that $f$ is smooth on entire closed disk (with the boundary).

---

*See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276096/let-m-be-a-smooth-manifold-and-let-n-be-a-manifold-with-boundary-if-df-p?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative to using invariance of domain.

We know that $f : D \to D$ must be a homeomorphism. Assume that $f(x) \in \partial D$ for some $x \in D^0$. Then $D \setminus \{x\}$ is homeomorphic to $D \setminus \{f(x)\}$. But $D \setminus \{f(x)\}$ is contractible and $D \setminus \{x\}$ is homotopy equivalent to the circle $S^1$. This is impossible.

Thus $f(D^0) \subset D^0$ and similarly $f^{-1}(D^0) \subset D^0$. Hence $f(D^0) = D^0$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $f:D\rightarrow D$ is a continuous bijection and $D$ is compact, we derive that $f$ is a homeomorphism. Let $g = f^{-1}$. By [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) we derive that $g(D^0)\subseteq D^0$. Hence we have (as you noticed)
$$\partial D\subseteq g(\partial D)$$
Thus 
$$f(\partial D) \subseteq f(g(\partial D)) = \partial D$$