# Uncertain about the statement "equivalent condition for an isometry of Riemannian manifolds" in Lee's Intro to Riemannian Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, isometry, diffeomorphism

In Professor Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds, second edition on page 12,
the first paragraph on Isometries reads

> Suppose $(M,g)$ and $(\tilde{M},\tilde{g})$ are Riemannian manifolds with or
> without boundary. An isometry from $(M,g)$ to $(\tilde{M},\tilde{g})$ is a diffeomorphism $\phi\colon M\to\tilde{M}$ such that $\phi^*\tilde{g}=g$.
> Unwinding the definitions shows that this is equivalent to the requirement that
> $\phi$ be a smooth bijection and each $d\phi_p\colon T_pM\to T_{\phi(p)}\tilde{M}$
> be a linear isometry.

Only one part of a proof eludes me. That is, given a smooth bijection $\phi$ such that each
$d\phi_p\colon T_pM\to T_{\phi(p)}\tilde{M}$ is a linear isometry, I haven't been able to prove that $\phi^{-1}$ is smooth if $M$ has nonempty boundary. When $M$
has no boundary, I can use his Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, second edition (ISM)
Proposition 4.8(a) and ISM Exercise 4.9 to get that $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism
and ISM Proposition 4.6(f) to get that $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism. ISM Proposition 4.8(a)
relies on the Inverse Function Theorem for Manifolds (ISM Theorem 4.5) which
Professor Lee warns us "can fail for a map whose domain has nonempty boundary."

[Is a map with invertible differential that maps boundary to boundary a local diffeomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1984346/527829) might be part of an answer if I
could prove that $\phi$ mapped the boundary of $M$ into the boundary of $\tilde{M}$. (I can already prove that it maps the interior of $M$ into the
interior of $\tilde{M}$ using ISM Problem 4-2.) Of course, such a requirement is necessary for $\phi$ to be a diffeomorphism by the
Diffeomorphism Invariance of the Boundary Theorem (ISM Theorem 2.18), but I haven't been able to prove that $\phi$ maps boundary to boundary either.

So, how can $\phi^{-1}$ be proven to be smooth, or is the statement in the book incorrect?

Comment: Have you considered mapping of $[0,1)$ onto $S^1$ given by $e^{2\pi i x}$? I think it's smooth, and definitely not diffeomorphism. The inner product is irrelevant to that part (you could make it preserve metric if you wanted), so it seems false.

Comment: I did consider that. However, since it has sine and cosine in it, there will be points where $d\phi_x$ is the zero map and therefore not invertible. So I think it is not a viable counterexample.

Comment: @JeffRubin It is of course a local diffeomorphism. I think you’d better double-check that vague reasoning.

Comment: It can't be a local diffeomorphism: since it is bijective it would then be a diffeomorphism, which it is not.

Comment: The derivative is an isomorphism at every point. The issue is point-set topology, not the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Using terminology from Lee ISM: Let $\phi\colon[0,1)\to S^1$ be defined by $\phi(t)=(\cos 2\pi t,\sin 2\pi t)$. Then $d\phi_t\colon T_t([0,1))\to T_{(\cos 2\pi t,\sin 2\pi t)}S^1$ is a linear map whose matrix with respect to coordinate bases is the Jacobian of the representative $\hat{\phi}$ with respect to smooth charts for $[0,1)$ and $S^1$, namely $([0,1),\mathrm{id}_{[0,1)})$ and $(U_i^\pm\cap S^1,\phi_i^\pm)$. In particular, $J_{1/2}(\phi_1^-\circ\phi)=\sin(2\pi/2)=0$, so no, the differential is not an isomorphism at $t=1/2$.

Comment: That should have been $2\pi\sin(2\pi/2)=0$ in the last sentence.

Comment: The issue with your reasoning is that $\phi(\frac 1 2)$ is not in set $U_1^-$, since it's $x$ coordinate is zero, and not negative. You have to consider domains of maps

Comment: * $y$ coordinate

Comment: From ISM page 5: $U^-_1=\{(x^1,x^2)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon x^1<0\}$, so $\phi(1/2)=(\cos\pi,\sin\pi)=(-1,0)\in U^-_1\cap S^1$, so $\phi(1/2)$ is most certainly in the  domain of the smooth chart $(U^-_1\cap S^1,\phi^-_1)$ for $S^1$.

Comment: And the chart is $\phi_1^-(x^1,x^2)=x^2$, and the derivative of $\sin[2\pi x)$ is $2\pi\color{red}{\cos}(2\pi x)$. It helps to visualize the mapping directly, too.

Comment: Oh! My apologies. You’re right! So it is a counterexample after all! If you write it as an answer, I’ll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @Esgeriath Why don’t you write it up? It was your suggestion.

Comment: @JeffRubin: You're absolutely right; these conditions are equivalent only when $M$ has empty boundary. I've added a correction to my [online list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/RM/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this asumptions, $\phi^{-1}$ cannot be proven to be smooth.

Consider $[0, 2\pi)$ and $S^1$ with standard smooth structures. Manifold $[0, 2\pi)$ has nonempty boundary $\partial [0, 2\pi) = \{0\}$.

The function $\phi\colon[0, 2 \pi) \to S^1$ given by $\phi(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t))$ is smooth bijection, but not diffeomorphism - inverse function is not continuous at
$(1, 0)$.

The part about $d\phi_t$ being linear isometry does not invalidate this example. This is kind of independent condition. But to be more formal,
we can endow both spaces with metric tensors by setting
$\frac\partial{\partial x^1}$ and $
d\phi\frac\partial{\partial x^1}
$
to be one-element orthonormal basis in corresponding manifolds.
Notice how vectors $d\phi_t \frac\partial{\partial x^1}$ are always nonzero, and thus definition is correct.
This deifnition gives us that $d\phi_t\colon T_t [0, 2\pi) \to T_{\phi(t)}S^1$ is isometry for each $t$.